# Keeping an image button in place and correct size, responsive to background image CSS

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm still just learning and not great with CSS but have the following code which places a BuyNow button over an image. I need it to stay stay in the correct position (responsive) when screen size changes. It's almost working but I think the Image button size is causing issues too. How do I keep this all together?

ASP.NET

```
<div class="image-container">
    <asp:Image ID="ImgAddCoins" style="width:100%;" alt="Add Coins Background" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/addCoins.png" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnCoinStack20" alt="Buy 20 Coins" runat="server" CommandArgument = "20" class="ppbutton"  OnClick="BuyCoins_Click" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/buttonBuy.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-container {
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
}

.ppbutton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2; 
  color: #fff;
  border: none; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with asp.net, but could you not have the container be a div, with a background image, and delete the image element? Then put styling on the image container div like:

```
.image-container {
  background-image: url("~/files/images/addCoins.png");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: 'center';
  align-items: 'center';
padding: 20px //or whatever you want it to be.
}
```

Display flex will become your CSS friend :) - read about it here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Remove position absolute and transforms etc from the Image button.

This means there is less HTML, less styling, and less use of absolute positioning.

Use the `background-size` attribute to cover / contain crop the background image. (I assume you don't need to support old browsers)

This answer assumes the image container won't have other content within it / you don't mind other content within it being center aligned.

Comment: @mark davies any success? Feel free to mark as the answer if so :D